# Response.End() throwing an Error

Tags: asp.net

In my application I need to download a file, So I am using this piece of code:

```
 Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";                    
 Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename =" + strFileName + ".xls");
 Response.TransmitFile(strFilePath);
 Response.End();
```

at `Response.End()` i am getting an error `ThreadAbortException`

To aviod this error I am trying to use httpApplication.CompleteRequest(),
but i m not able to use this too.

The code with httpApplication.CompleteRequest() is below,

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename =" + strFileName + ".xls");
Response.TransmitFile(strFilePath);
HttpApplication.CompleteRequest();
```

I m getting this error when i m using HttpApplication.CompleteRequest()

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.HttpApplication.CompleteRequest()'
```

I hope i m able to make my doubt clear...
help me out....

Comment: What exactly is the message of your `ThreadAbortException`?

Comment: this was the error         
"Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack"

Comment: You could use a generic handler (.ashx file) to serve the file instead of serving it from an aspx page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Response.End()` is expected to throw a `ThreadAbortException`.
This is by design, so that the rest of the page response is not processed.

It is perfectly ok to get this exception, and it will ensure the page is not processed further.

Refer: [HttpResponse.End](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end.aspx)

> The CompleteRequest method does not raise an exception, and code after
>   the call to the CompleteRequest method might be executed. If your
>   intention is to avoid execution of subsequent code, and if the
>   performance penalty of End is acceptable, you can call End instead of
>   CompleteRequest.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename =" + strFileName + ".xls");
Response.TransmitFile(strFilePath);
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occures because you are using a ASP update panel or any control using JavaScript. Try to use control native from ASP or HTML without JavaScript or ScriptManager or scripting.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this problem and have solved it with the following code

```
ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
              sm.RegisterPostBackControl(this.grid);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just comment this line and you're good to go:

```
//Response.End();
```

It worked for me :)